# How to make dark overlay for 4 divs using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 divs with image as background and I want them all to have a dark overlay, but the absolute position is somehow messing things up because all 4 overlays end up over the first div when I want each to include all 4 divs.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `<div class="overlay1"></div>` tag inside `factorImg1` div and give it to `position:relative`. Do same thing in all respective div.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the `.overlay` as a child of the `.factorImg` div and make `.factorImg` have `position: relative`, otherwise the `.overlay` will be set absolute to `.row`.

You could also look into pseudo-classe (`:before` and `:after`):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: Thank you for the info, tried the above answer first and worked but thanks a lot for your solution too!

Answer (score 1):

Put your `overlay` divs inside bootstrap columns which will have `display: relative` by default. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
.overlay1,
.overlay2,
.overlay3,
.overlay4 {
  width: 14.7%;
  height: 270px;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.factorImgText {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 5px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
}

.factorSection h6,
.factorSection p {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.factorSection h6 {
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
}

.factorSection p {
  font-size: .75em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.factorImg1,
.factorImg2,
.factorImg3,
.factorImg4 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 8%;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 270px;
  width: 23.8%;
  position: relative;
}

.factorImg1 {
  background-image: url('http://kleingartenverein-aligse.de//images/wallpaper/Oct/fall-1072821_1920.jpg');
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.factorImg2 {
  background-image: url('http://kleingartenverein-aligse.de//images/wallpaper/Oct/fall-1072821_1920.jpg');
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.factorImg3 {
  background-image: url("http://kleingartenverein-aligse.de//images/wallpaper/Oct/fall-1072821_1920.jpg");
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.factorImg4 {
  background-image: url("http://kleingartenverein-aligse.de//images/wallpaper/Oct/fall-1072821_1920.jpg");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="background_section2">
  <div id="section2-05" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
        <h2>¿QUÉ ES EL FACTOR ZURPRAIS?</h2>
        <p>¡Mucho más que el factor sorpresa!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row factorSection">

      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 factorImg1">
        <div class="factorImgText">
          <h6>2 DÍAS ANTES… ¡ZURPRAIS!</h6>
          <p>Con tu pack de experiencias, tu edad y tu perfil (familias, parejas, amig@s…), organizaremos tu plan… Y como es Zurprais, 2 días antes sabrás lo que es.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 factorImg2">
        <div class="factorImgText">
          <h6>PLANES CON UN PLUS</h6>
          <p>Un atardecer en velero… ¿con cava y ostras? Un brunch… ¿entre viñedos? Todas tus experiencias tendrán un toque extra que las hará aún más especiales.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 factorImg3">
        <div class="factorImgText">
          <h6>EMOCIÓN DESDE LA RESERVA</h6>
          <p>Al reservar, empieza el juego. Recibirás algunas pistas sobre las actividades que te podrían tocar. Para que vayas calentando motores.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 factorImg4">
        <div class="factorImgText">
          <h6>CAMBIO GRATUITO</h6>
          <p>¡Segurísimo que tu plan te va a encantar! Pero para que estés tranquil@: si no te gusta lo que te hemos organizado, te preparamos uno diferente para otro día.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```